# how to enforce checkout for a single file not the whole library in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, checkout, single-file

I have a document library in SharePoint 2010, and I would like to enforce checkout for only one of the files and not the whole library. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is no way to do that, as this configuration is set per library/list and can not be set per file.

You should try to convince users to create a separate library for files where requirements states that they need to be checked-out/checked-in.

Comment: Thank you Foca so much for getting back to me. I know that this feature is list based, which is why I was looking for a not-out-of-box workaround. May be a script?

Comment: You're welcome @Lobna. I'm trying to think about something, but so far nothing came to my mind,... maybe thinking backwards would help (as we can't avoid turning on check-in/check-out at the library level). So, what about something that would make the process transparent for the user when the file doesn't require check-out, and let it go for the file that requires? (I have no idea whether is possible,... just wondering)